# Any way to debug php4.3 or php4.4 using Apache2 on windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, apache2, php4, dbg

I believe I've tried every possible approach to setting up a debugging envronment in windows using apache2 and php4 but failed with all of them.
I have a couple of apache instances both for php4.3 and php4.4. I got xdebug installed on the 4.4 version (couldn't find a working module for php4.3) but it seems that there is no IDE/client that would work with the older xdebug versions. Then I switched over to the DBG approach. It simply won't load on either version. Tried the last 2 DBG windows binary releases but neither of them would load with php. phpinfo()'s output shows no sign of the DBG module, as well as command line "php -m" doesn't have it either.
I also can't seem to find a way to run php4 as fast cgi on apache 2 under windows. There's only one executable (php.exe) that goes with the php4 binaries for windows (no php-cgi.exe). My apache/php setup is:
Apache/2.0.64 (Win32) PHP/4.4.1 (phpinfo won't mention anything about thread safety, "php -i" would show thread safety as enabled"
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler

php.ini DBG section:
Tried all of the following for loading the extension (neither works)
    zend_extension_ts="C:\PHP\php4.4.1\extensions\php_dbg.dll"
or
    zend_extension_ts=php_dbg.dll
or
    extension="C:\PHP\php4.4.1\extensions\php_dbg.dll"
or
    extension=php_dbg.dll

```
[debugger]
debugger.enabled = true
debugger.profiler_enabled = true
debugger.JIT_host = clienthost
debugger.JIT_port = 7869
```

Tried php DBG packages:
    dbg-2.13.1-win32.zip
    dbg-2.15.5-win32.zip
using the php_dbg.dll-4.4.x (i just renamed it to php_dbg.dll) then copied over to the php extensions directory.

Using windows 7 x64

Comment: PHP 4.4.1 is nearly seven years old -- it's ANCIENT. Please upgrade to a modern version of PHP and try again.

Comment: I agree but the situation is such that the website I have to work on is installed onto a php4 server and all the thousands of scripts it contains won't run on php5. I have no choice here...